# Brightness control not working in Lenovo G580

Tags: nvidia, brightness, lenovo

I purchased a new Lenovo g580 laptop. But I am totally disappointed when I installed Ubuntu on it. Almost all drivers are not working. :-( 
The laptop configuration is
 intel i3 processor
 **Nvidia GeForce 610M graphics card**.

I couldn't find the nvidia drivers in the additional drivers (jockey). 
The main problem is that the brightness control not working. I tried lots of methods explained in this site, but the result again disappointed me.

I am a student and I am using Linux, and the brightness control is the most urgent problem that have to be solved.

So experts please give me a solution.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following line to `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` in the "Device" section for your GPU:

`Option "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1"`

Then restart X and see if the brightness controls work.
Probably the easiest way to restart X is to simple reboot the computer.

Source [here](http://www.nvnews.net/vbulletin/showthread.php?p=2204839#post2204839).

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what the problem is only with that information.

You could start by looking the directories under 
/sys/class/backlight/
there should be a couple of them.

Try to set the brightness by manually changing the file "brightness" in one of these directories (you have to do it as root)

Comment: The problem is simply i cannot control the brightness using the function keys.

Comment: Which version of ubuntu? (10.04/10.10/11.04/11.10/12.04/12.10/13.04)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can install *xbacklight* from USC and setup a start up entry with the command 
`xbacklight -set %`
 where you put your numbers in place of `%`

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it may solve you problem.It solved my problem on Acer aspire 4736 :

Open terminal by hittin <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> and apply this command.

```
sudo setpci -s 00:02.0 f4.b=xx
```

Here replace `xx` between **00**[Bright] to **ff**[Dark]. It is a hexadecimal value that control your brightness.

For more information visit [this link](http://daksh21ubuntu.blogspot.in/2011/12/how-to-increasedecrease-brightness-on.html).