# Lenovo G580 Brightness

Tags: lenovo

I recently acquired a new laptop, a Lenovo G580 (i5, 4GB) and I am experiencing some issues with the brightness control in ubuntu.

I think that is because of the nvidia vga (which is integrated with the i5, hd4000 graphics). I have tried many "solutions" without success. As I am totally novice with Linux (but not with computers), please, try to be explicit in answers, this would really help.

I have modified the grub with `backlight=vendor`, making possible to see the brightness control bar, but when y slide it it make no changes at all in the bright who is always at maximum.

I have also tried re-installing ubuntu 12.04 LTS and 13.10.

p.s. I apologize about my english...

Comment: What about [Brightness controll not working in lenovo g580](http://askubuntu.com/questions/198108/brightness-controll-not-working-in-lenovo-g580)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

And add/edit to `/etc/default/grub` in the variable "GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT":

```
acpi_osi=\"!Windows 2012\"
```

e.g:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=\"!Windows 2012\""
```

Then run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

For me, works flowless for Lenovo G480.